# Header Multiple Redefinition

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I understand that this question has been asked to death, but I've done a decent amount of research and nothing has helped so far. Yes I have lots and lots of header guards No as far as I know nothing needs inline every function is within a class. I have a encoderrunner.cpp that includes encoder.h and decoder.h both encoder.h and decoder.h include FrequencyTable.h and that's where all hell breaks loose, the compiler says that everything within FrequencyTable is a redefinition. this is one of many this just happens to be from the class i separated from FrequencyTable

```
/home/sersay/Documents/ECS60/p4/FrequencyNode.cpp:10: multiple definition of `FrequencyNode::FrequencyNode(unsigned char, FrequencyNode*, FrequencyNode*)'
decoder.o:/home/sersay/Documents/ECS60/p4/FrequencyNode.cpp:10: first defined here
```

etc...

- I've had/added header guards including trying #pragma once
- FrequencyTable was originally a nested class so I tried separating it into two classes, still same error
- I do have functions outside classes but they don't exist in my FrequencyTable class or the other class i separated from it

I can provide more code but I don't believe its entirely relevant, perhaps it is how i'm compiling it?

```
encoder.out : decoder.o encoder.o encoderRunner.o  
g++ -ansi -Wall -g -o encoder.out decoder.o encoder.o encoderRunner.o  

decoder.o : decoder.cpp decoder.h 
g++ -ansi -Wall -g -c decoder.cpp

encoder.o : encoder.cpp encoder.h 
g++ -ansi -Wall -g -c encoder.cpp

encoderRunner.o : encoderRunner.cpp CPUTimer.h encoder.h decoder.h 
g++ -ansi -Wall -g -c encoderRunner.cpp

clean : 
rm -f encoder.out decoder.o  encoder.o  encoderRunner.o
```

Edit1:

```
    #pragma once
    #ifndef FrequencyTable_H_
    #define FrequencyTable_H_

    #include "FrequencyNode.h"

    //class FrequencyNode;

    class FrequencyTable
    {
    private:
        FrequencyNode *HighestNode;
        FrequencyNode *LowestNode;
    public:
        FrequencyTable();
        ~FrequencyTable();
        FrequencyNode * insert(unsigned char symbol); //USE THIS for new values in hash
        unsigned char * GetOrder();

    };


//#include "FrequencyTable.cpp"
#endif
```

Edit2(Ed's Request):

```
#include "FrequencyTable.h"
#include "FrequencyNode.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
```

please let me know what other information you need

Comment: Can you create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: This isn't your real code, because you never even _built_ `FrequencyNode.cpp`. Or are you including that into a header? Don't.

Comment: It looks like one of your files is #include-ing FrequencyNode.cpp. You definitely don't want that.

Comment: I didn't create the makefile, its what my professor is going to use to make the project, i assumed the makefile will create my classes from within encoder and decoder which he outlined

Comment: NathanOliver, the problem occurred when I included #FrequencyTable into decoder.cpp after i'd finished working on encoder.cpp so this is sort of the smallest example i can give

Comment: @Sersay _`//#include "FrequencyTable.cpp"`_ If that was the offending code, you should extend the makefile instead, to compile and link `FrequencyTable.cpp`.

Comment: The top bit (#includes) of frequencytable.cpp would be handy

Answer (score 0):

I was sensing that it had to do with compilation but thanks to @Lightness Races in Orbit and @πάντα ῥεῖ I rewrote my makefile to be

```
encoder.out : FrequencyNode.o FrequencyTable.o decoder.o encoder.o encoderRunner.o  
    g++ -ansi -Wall -g -o encoder.out FrequencyTable.o FrequencyNode.o decoder.o encoder.o encoderRunner.o  

FrequencyNode.o : FrequencyNode.cpp FrequencyTable.h
    g++ -ansi -Wall -g -c FrequencyNode.cpp

FrequencyTable.o : FrequencyTable.cpp FrequencyTable.h FrequencyNode.h
    g++ -ansi -Wall -g -c FrequencyTable.cpp

decoder.o : decoder.cpp decoder.h FrequencyTable.h FrequencyNode.h
    g++ -ansi -Wall -g -c decoder.cpp

encoder.o : encoder.cpp encoder.h FrequencyTable.h FrequencyNode.h
    g++ -ansi -Wall -g -c encoder.cpp

encoderRunner.o : encoderRunner.cpp CPUTimer.h encoder.h decoder.h FrequencyTable.h FrequencyNode.h
    g++ -ansi -Wall -g -c encoderRunner.cpp

clean : 
rm -f encoder.out FrequencyTable.o FrequencyNode.o decoder.o encoder.o encoderRunner.o
```

This being said, I know you don't have to specifically compile things like iostream and stdlib.h? is this because they use inline or are templates, can anyone link me to something that can explain this, or explain it themselves?